# How to upload the Prestashop database to server?

Tags: prestashop

I'm working on Prestashop right now. I had to make some changes in the design of a Prestashop website. I have made those changes at my database. but how to upload those changes on the server I'm not able to do it. please will any one tell me the process?

Firstly I created my db in phpmyadmin, made the changes in Prestashop & then tried to upload the db and the changes onto the server but it gives this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

By the way, I would like to know how to change the username root and blank password in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Did you try something..?

Comment: yes i firstly created my db in myphpadmin, made the changes in Prestashop & then tried to upload the db and the changes onto the server but it gives error

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) i am getting this error

Comment: also i waned to know that how to change the username root and blank password in phpmyadmin....